# unable to send logs in IBM Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am having a issue with logs created by IBM Mobilefirst after taking the latest update of 7.1 version. I was able to log before and also was able to send the logs but after taking the update it stopped showing logs on android monitor and also not able to send logs to server.

I am seeing the following error.

> com.worklight.common.Logger:
>   com.worklight.common.Logger.setContext(Context) must be called to
>   fully enable debug log capture.  Currently, the 'capture' flag is set
>   but the 'context' field is not.  This warning will only be printed
>   once.

When do we get this error any issue with my libs or with my code.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of issue is it recommended that you will open an IBM PMR (support ticket) as the question does not fit Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sure Idan. I will raise a support ticket.